# Memory Access Performance in Java Card

Tags: performance, memory, smartcard, javacard

Supposing that I instanced a persisant byte array in Java Card with a length of 30 000 (`byte[] array = new byte[(short) 0x7530];`) that I run through everytime I use my applet.
I also instanced an index `i` that I set everytime I run through my array to 'remember' at which cell start the next time.

My question is the following : **Can it be slower to get the *nth* cell than getting the first one if my array has a big length (like 30000 in this case) using** `array[i]` ?
In other words, can the instruction `array[(short)0x7500]` take more time than `array[(short) 0x0000]` and if the response is "yes" could you explain me why ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, memory gets loaded on a page by page basis. If your array ends up in two or more pages, and only the first page gets loaded by the JIT (because reasons, it's very hard to track memory once the JIT and GC touch it) but the last one isn't loaded yet, accessing the last cell would cause a [page fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault).

The effect on L1/L2 cache and so on aside (it gets very complicated), a page fault is still extremely expensive relative to a simple DMA read. Last I heard, it locked the entire bus **for every single core you're using to read, for the duration of the entire read**, so the problem would get exacerbated by multiple threads accessing the large array at random.

We're talking about pretty large arrays here, many pages get mapped at a time so you'd have to have many, many such reads with a short spike each time you page fault. Don't expect to see it easily in test cases, but it's good to be aware of the problem. In particular read rectangular arrays row-first! (also helps with L1/L2 caching)